# Creating a dynamic pivot column from a row in php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to create a pivot column out of a row but getting some challenges with php. When i run my query in mysql consol, it works very well and returns the required values. But when I run it in php it returns a mysql syntax error. i have failed to figure out what the real problem is.
The queries are bellow for both plain mysql and for php respectively

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when Ref_Month = ''',
      Ref_Month,
      ''' then Total_Income end) AS ''',
      Ref_Month, ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql 
FROM  mytable; 

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Tone_Name, ', @sql, ' FROM mytable  WHERE Ref_Year in (2015) GROUP BY Tone_Name limit 10');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

for PHP/codeigniter

```
$query = $this->db->query("SET @sql = NULL;SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('sum(case when Ref_Month = ''', Ref_Month, ''' then Total_Income end) AS ''', Ref_Month, '''')) INTO @sql FROM  mytable; SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Tone_Name, ', @sql, ' FROM mytable  WHERE Ref_Year in (2015) GROUP BY Tone_Name limit 10'); PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;");
```

The error message received was:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('sum(case when Ref_Month = ''', Ref_Month, '' Ã la ligne 1

Someone please help me. I also want to know how to display such columns and rows in HTML/PHP for front end.

Thanks.

Comment: Pls share the MySQL syntax error with us!

Comment: Hello @Anant, am not clearly getting you. my query is like th eone you first posted. Thanks

Comment: A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064
Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('sum(case when Ref_Month = ''', Ref_Month, '' Ã  la ligne 1

( here is supposed to be the query itself)
Filename: C:\wamp\www\crbt\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330

Comment: did you found the answer on how run prepared statement on CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0):

You are running multiple queries in a single query() method call. The standard MySQL database drivers have separate methods to execute multiple sql queries in a single call, but CI uses the standard call that allow only a single sql command to be executed per call.

Execute each of the sql statements in separate CI query calls:

```
$this->db->query("SET @sql = NULL");
...
$this->db->query("DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt");
```

Although you can do all the string concatenation in php yourself, so you would not need to use MySQL's prepared statements at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shadow. Yes I wanted to do the string concatenation in php with a normal MYSQL query but there is a way am messing up.